# Parser error in scala can't create object main

Tags: scala

I am creating a parser in Scala:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._
// Parser of protocol

object Parser extends RegexParsers {  
  //code
}
```

When creating my main object like this:

```
import Parser._

object main extends Parser {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
 {
 }
}
```

I get the following: object creation impossible, since method apply in class Parser of type (in: Parser.Input)Parser.ParseResult[Nothing] is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to extend 
[scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers.Parser](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala-parser-combinators/scala/util/parsing/combinator/Parsers$Parser.html), which has an abstract method `apply` that you need to override in order to subclass it with an object.

```
object Main extends Parser {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  }

  def apply(in: Input) = ???
}
```

Note that this is **not** the same Parser that you declared in your first snippet.